# Computing Gaussian-Weighted Integrals for Small Lengthscales

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion, approximation, gaussian-integral

I am attempting to compute the following integral:

$$ I(l) = \int_{[-1,1]^2}dxdy \sqrt{1-x^2} \sqrt{1-y^2}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{l^2}} $$

I am using Mathematica for symbolic calculations and translating the results into a Fortran code with the help of Mathematica's `FortranForm` function. This method will be invoked frequently, so it is crucial to have a formula that is both simple and executes very quickly. Numerical integration methods are not suitable for this purpose.

If $ l \gg 1 $ or$ l \sim 1 $, I can easily find a solution using series expansion, ChebyshevT, or Pade approximation. However, none of these approaches works effectively when $l \ll 1 $ because the Gaussian becomes very thin, unlike the nearly constant behavior observed when $ l \gg 1 $. Do you have any suggestions on how to address this issue?

It's also worth mentioning that I will need to compute integrals of the form:

$$ J(x; l) = \int_{-1}^{1}dy \sqrt{1-y^2} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{l^2}} $$

So, numerically computing the integral and fitting some curve on it might not be the best idea.

Thanks in advance,
L.

Comment: Laplace method (saddle point)

Comment: In $J$, what is the domain of $x$, and do you need your approximation to be continuous as a function of $x$? Also, what is your error tolerance? Finally, is your budget for computing time to cook up your formula more or less arbitrarily large?

Comment: To be clear, if I infer from the definition of $I$ that the domain of $x$ in $J$ is $[-1,1]$, the Laplace method encounters a difficulty where as $x \to 0^+$, there is a transition between the region to the left of $x$ having a significant contribution to the integration to it not having a significant contribution anymore, and  the usual Laplace method without any modification can't handle that. There is an analogous difficulty as $x \to 1^-$.

Comment: @ian can you elaborate? Laplace's method works when the peak is at the edge of the domain as well.

Comment: @user619894 Think about $F(x,M)=\frac{\int_0^1 e^{-M (x-y)^2} dy}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-M(x-y)^2 dy}}$ for large $M$. For $x$ not too close to $0$ or $1$, the Laplace method extends the domain of integration to $\mathbb{R}$ which adds a negligible amount to the result of the integration, and so you get $1$. For $x=0$, the Laplace method instead extends the integral to $[0,\infty)$, which again adds a negligible amount to the integration, and so you get $1/2$.

Comment: @user619894 (Cont.) But when $x$ is rather close to $0$, but not exactly there, the method still extends the domain of integration to $\mathbb{R}$ and you get $1$. $F$ is clearly a continuous function of $x$ but the approximation is not.

Comment: @ian it is a question of limit orders. As long as $l^2$ is much smaller that the $x$ gap, Laplace holds, If not, you can still treat the  "finite" part of the integration range by an $\erf$, and an expansion of $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ near the edge.

Comment: @user619894 Yes...except that actually using "erf" there is no longer strictly speaking the Laplace method at all. That is the point I was making. It's not impossible to fix, but it needs fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Update: It appears that the first integral has a solution. Taylor expanding the Gaussian leads to an infinite series, each term is easy to integrate and, by luck, the infinite sum can be rewritten into a simple expression using `HyperGeometricPFQ` functions. Since those functions have existing implementations that are numerically stable, I am totally happy with that.

However, I am still struggling with the second integral $J(x;l)$, and the series does not seem to be converging to a simple expression in that case...

Answer (score 0):

$$I(x;l)=\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{(1-y^{2})}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^{2}}{l^{2}}}dy $$

For small $l$ , the integral is dominated by the largest value of the exponential. Thus, when $-1<x<1$ we can ignore all $y$ that are not very near $x$ and write $y=x+t$

$$I(x;l)=\int\sqrt{(1-(x+t)^{2}}e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{l^{2}}}dt\approx\int\left(1-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+O(t^{2})\right)e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{l^{2}}}dt\approx(1-\frac{1}{2}x^{2})\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{l^{2}}}dt$$

At precisely $x=-1$ we may still use this method, but the peak is is at the edge, so we should use half the value.

When $|x|>1$ we can expand near the larger domain edge, e.g. when $x<-1$, expand near $y=-1$ setting $y\approx-1+t$:

$$I(x;l)=\int\sqrt{(1-(-1+t))(1+(-1+t)}e^{-\frac{(x+1-t)^{2}}{l^{2}}}=\int\sqrt{(2-t)t}e^{-\frac{(x+1)^{2}}{l^{2}}+\frac{(x+1)t}{l^{2}}-\frac{t^{2}}{l^{2}}}dt$$

For small $l$ we can ignore the $\left(\frac{t}{l}\right)^{2}$ term in the exponential, since it kicks in after $|\frac{(x+1)t}{l^{2}}|$ becomes large and the rest of the integral is negligible, so that

$$I(x;l)\approx2e^{-\frac{(x+1)^{2}}{l^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{t}e^{\frac{(x+1)}{l^{2}}t}dt$$
(recall that x+1<0 so the integral converges).

**Edit**
As @ian pointed out, when $x$ is close to the integration endpoints, special care needs to be taken, since the Gaussian integral can't be assumed to extend from $(-\infty,\infty)$. I have ignored this edge case in my answer.